# how to get the session Id for web service calls to salesforce

Tags: webservices, apex-webservice

I have implemented a web service in salesforce and generated the WSDL for the web service and provided it to the external system. However while invoking a call, we need to pass the session id in teh request. How can the external system get the session Id? Can we create a connected app and provide them the required details to get the session id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set your `endpoint` of your server.

1. Endpoint URL (Sandbox)-> `https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/35.0`
2. Endpoint URL (Production)-> `https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/35.0`

Set your `headers` as below:

1. SOAPAction-> ""
2. Content-Type-> text/xml

And finally `Body`. Replace Login Id and Password with actual credentials:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:login>
         <urn:username>Login ID</urn:username>
         <urn:password>Password</urn:password>
      </urn:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In response, you will get `SessionId`.

Once you've `SessionId`, set your endpoint URL as follows:

`https://domain_name.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/YourWebServiceName`

Again set `Headers` as follows:

1. Authorization-> Bearer
2. Content-Type-> application/json

And `Body`:

```
{
  "name":"ABC"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. However I am using a custom web service and the endpoint will contain the apex web service name. Should this call be included in the same request to the web service Or should this call be made first to retrieve the session details and then use it to call the web service

Comment: @SFDCLearner You will need 2 request. 1st to get `sessionId` and 2nd, use that `sessionId` to call your webservice. Refer Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Rohit! the second actual request can be made in xml as well i guess right? Let me try this and come back!

Comment: @SFDCLearner I haven't tried for xml but I think it's possible.